# Isolate external php code in Laravel

Tags: laravel, revolution-slider, isolation

I need to integrate [Slider Revolution editor](https://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-jquery-visual-editor-addon/13934907)  into my Laravel (5.5) app.

I've put the editor in `public/revslider/` folder to be able to use the visual editor. I also created a helper class to "communicate" with it and be able to use it inside my Blade views:

```
namespace App\Helpers;

include( public_path('revslider/embed.php') );

class Slider{

/**
 * This function is called where you want to put your slider
 */
public static function make($slider){
    return \RevSliderEmbedder::putRevSlider( $slider );
}

/**
 * This function is called inside <HEAD> tag to include all 
 * SR assets (js/css/font files)
 */
public static function head(){
    return \RevSliderEmbedder::headIncludes(false); 
}

}
```

The SR's PHP code does not use namespaces. In fact it is a strange mix of Code Igniter, Wordpress and vanilla php.

The problem is it is trying to declare a translation function `__(...)`:

```
if( ! function_exists('__'))
{
    function __($string = '')
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

and since there is already such Laravel's helper function, it does not redeclare it and tries to use Laravel's `__()` function. And that obviously causes errors.

I temporarily managed to fix this problem by changing the name of SR's `__()` function (and all references to it). But of course it is not a best way to solve this problem, since I will be unable to use SR's automatic updates or will be forced to do these changes after every update.

So my questions are:

1. **Is there any good way of integrating such "bad" code into your project, invoking it safely without conflicts?** Is there any way of isolating such code and avoid clashes? By "bad code" I mean code that does not follow strict OOP/PSR rules present in projects like Laravel.
2. **What is the best way to include "external" PHP code?** I've just used plain `include()` inside of my helper class' file, but is there a better/cleaner way? Like, I don't know, loading it through composer?

Comment: So you are asking is there a better way to include `helper` functions for `RevSlider` in `Laravel app`?

Comment: Yes and no. I'm asking is there a way of calling SR's `\RevSliderEmbedder::headIncludes(false);` function in some kind of isolated way, so it won't clash with Laravel's functions.

Comment: No I don't think so, even if you do somehow, how are you resolve which `__` function will be called (RevSlider or Laravel) when you call it..and even if you succeed at this, one of `__` function won't be registered because the other one will be already created so it will just skip creation, hope ti clarifies it

Comment: Yes - that is the situation right now. I'm just curious if there IS any way of isolating such code. Then inside of this isolated "environment" the SR's `__` function will be called, and Laravel's `__` function everywhere else.

Comment: Never encountered this issue, but my wild guess is that you can certainly achieve this through `composer.json`, if he doesn't provide any `way around this` than I hardly think you will find anything

Comment: @Gacek did you find a solution for that at the end ?

Comment: @unknown unfortunately not

Comment: @Gacek so at the end u did not integrate your laravel project with slider revolution? because i'm wondering does laravel project support this plugin